# leaflet use satellite view, drupal 8?

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet, drupal-8

[image: Satellite view]

I need instead of a basic view in leaflet (it's a map of the world), the satellite view, but I still need to be able to switch between them? How does this work, can anyone explain this to me?

Installed modules:

https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap

https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps

Comment: See http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#basemap-providers

Comment: thanks! couldn't find that. Helps out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a more detailed example of my question, but @JulienV came close to what I meant, But it wasn't entirely what I wanted, plus I already found his exact answer in another post. What I wanted was to know how to add more or less maps to the view:

```
var osmLink = '<a href=\"https://openstreetmap.org\">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    thunLink = '<a href=\"https://thunderforest.com/\">Thunderforest</a>';

var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    osmAttrib = '&copy; ' + osmLink + ' Contributors',
    landUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    thunAttrib = '&copy; '+osmLink+' Contributors & '+thunLink;

var osmMap = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib}),
    landMap = L.tileLayer(landUrl, {attribution: thunAttrib});

var roadmap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});

var satellite = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});

var sat_text = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});
```

And then I added each map to the array like this:

```
if($map_layouts['get_roads']) {
    $roads = "\"Roads\": roadmap";

    if($baselist == "") {
        $baselist = $roads;
    } else {
        $baselist = $baselist . "," . $roads;
    }
}
```

Then I needed to check if the `$baselist` wasn't empty:

```
if($baselist) {
    $base_layout = "var baseLayers = {".$baselist."};";
} else {
    $base_layout = "";
}
```

And then of course add the layers to the map:

```
L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
```

I worked out the code with the `google maps` included. The `osm` and `thun` map was a nice example, but basically what this code does:

- First I make `if` statements in `php` to see if the roads are included in the button I made. I pass the `get_roads` inside the array, so that the `if` statement returns true and then it sets `$roads` as the `roadmap` value, which is given in the `map examples` in the first code of this answer.
- Then I check if `$baselist` isn't empty, because if it's empty it doesn't need a `,`, but if it isn't empty, then it gets the `$baselist`, which would be the previous set value, then a comma and then the new value.
- This was the markup of the layers and then I will pass the `baseLayers` as those values, which will create the maps inside the `leaflet` view, if the buttons are checked.

Answer (score 2):

Without using any external plugin :

```
gpxpod.map = new L.Map('map', {
    zoomControl: true
});

var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2013 <a href="http://openstreetmap'+
'.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttribution});

var esriAerialUrl = 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services'+
'/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}';
var esriAerialAttrib = 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, '+
'USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the'+
' GIS User Community';
var esriAerial = new L.TileLayer(esriAerialUrl,
    {maxZoom: 18, attribution: esriAerialAttrib});

var gUrl = 'http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}';
var gAttribution = 'google';
var googlesat = new L.TileLayer(gUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: gAttribution});

var baseLayers = {
    'OpenStreetMap': osm,
    'ESRI Aerial': esriAerial,
    'Google map sat': googlesat
}

L.control.layers(baseLayers, {}).addTo(map);
```

This piece of code adds a standard control to switch between tile provider layers. It includes two satellite tile providers.

More info : http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#control-layers

Comment: The problem is that this isn't how it works in drupal-8 sadly, the things that you're creating here are already generated in the gmap / more maps modules (sorry, I forgot to mention these modules), but indeed for without any plugins it works perfectly. Yesterday the problem luckily was already solved, but thanks anyway for all the help!